# Seeming simple T-SQL query surprisingly slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've pulled out (and anonymized) some lines from a stored procedure for a school district database (SQL Server 2008R2):

```
INSERT INTO ClassFilter -- guaranteed empty
SELECT
    Class.iClassID,
    'Literal Text',
    COUNT(iStudentID)
FROM
    Class INNER JOIN StudentClass ON Class.iClassID = StudentClass.iClassID
GROUP BY
    Class.iClassID
```

The `Class` table has only 2000 entries, and `ClassStudent` has about 30,000. The stored procedure that does this takes about 25 seconds to complete, and I'd like to trim that way down if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I'm brand new to creating my own indexes (the database is provided by an outside vendor), but I gave this a try:
<br />
    CREATE INDEX StuClassStu ON StudentClass(iStudentID)<br />
    CREATE INDEX StuClassCls ON StudentClass(iClassID)<br />
<br />
The procedure now runs in under two seconds, so THANKS, all!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on iClassID? Looks like you need one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's that slow is probably you're missing a couple indexes or you have too many indexes.

I would make sure you have a primary key on your class table as well as an index on the iClassId in the studentclass table.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this should take no time at all, even if you have many indexes, unless you have big `literal` and a `CLUSTERED INDEX` indexing that literal it.

did you look at the `Execution Plan`?

would you try accumulating inside a `CTE` before the `update` and the doing the `UPDATE` something like this:

```
;WITH StudentsInClass AS
(
    SELECT iClassID, COUNT(0)  AS StudentsCount
    FROM StudentClass
    GROUP BY iClassID
)
INSERT INTO ClassFilter -- guaranteed empty
SELECT
    Class.iClassID,
    'Literal Text',
    StudentsCount
FROM Class 
INNER JOIN StudentsInClass  ON Class.iClassID = StudentsInClass.iClassID
```

Comment: As I say, the indexing alone made a huge difference, but I'll give this a try as well.

Comment: `SQL Server` should handle 30k without indexing in no time. indexes should be added when you need it. That's the reason I asked if you looked at the `Execution Plan`, it tells a lot.

Comment: And now it's even faster--blink of an eye. Thanks to all on this issue.

Comment: I've been learning SQL "on the job". I'll hunt up documentation for this "Execution Plan" of which you speak. 

There's budget money for more formal training this year. Is there a program you might recommend?

Comment: tough question. are you a application developer? if so, , I would start with a basic course of `SQL Server for developers`, and then a course for `Performance Tunning` or `Optimization` or `advanced queries` there are also many different official courses by Microsoft, just Google for them.